# ElectronJs: HellowWorld application is not starting

Tags: node.js, npm, chromium, electron

I have started with electron js hello world application
[first application with electron](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/)

I am doing exactly what is instructed.

Created 3 files `main.js, index.html, package.json`

package.json

```
    {
  "name"    : "your-app",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js"
    }
```

main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const {app} = electron;
// Module to create native browser window.
const {BrowserWindow} = electron;

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

then installed Electron Globaly

```
npm install electron-prebuilt -g
```

then trying to run the application using

```
electron .
```

but nothing is happening. Here is the result

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\electrons\1>electron .

C:\Users\abc\Desktop\electrons\1>
```

**--- EDIT**

I have tried added script in package.json to start the electron

{
...
"scripts":{"start":"electron main.js"}
...
}

and then when I ran the app using `npm start`
Here is the result

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\electrons\1>npm start

> your-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\abc\Desktop\electrons\1
> electron main.js


npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\
\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! your-app@0.1.0 start: `electron main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225781
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the your-app@0.1.0 start script 'electron main.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the your-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     electron main.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs your-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls your-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abc\Desktop\electrons\1\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\abc\Desktop\electrons\1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Electron 1.1.0 and don't have VS2015 installed then you might be missing the [VC++2015 runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Comment: When I am packaging the app and shipping on some other system then its not running and prompting missing dlls `msvcp140.dll and vcruntime140.dll`

Comment: @VikasBansal You need to install the VC++2015 runtime on the other system too then, or package the missing dlls with your app (they'll need to be copied to the same directory as your app executable). None of this should be necessary in the next Electron release because it has already been fixed in the `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me, so it must be something in your environment. Try deleting the node_modules folder of the project (`rm -rf node_modules`), then `npm i` and then `npm start` (I'm assuming you still have the start task in your package.json).