# ElectronJs Quick Start not starting?

Tags: electron

I am new begin electronjs on windows, before I am used on linux not lived any problem like this.

My problem is when I am give CMD `npm start` then no any errors but don't opening any windows only terminal looking like this:

> C:\Users\Ramazan\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master>npm start
>
> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Ramazan\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master
>
> electron .

And nothing, I find this subject but [Why doesn't npm start run electron app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370512/why-doesnt-npm-start-run-electron-app) and this [ElectronJs: HellowWorld application is not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316414/electronjs-hellowworld-application-is-not-starting) But not working vc++ 2015 already installed on my pc and I tried reinstall 5 times node_modules folder.

How can I do for this problem?

Comment: Which nodejs do you have on your machine? LTS or Current?

Comment: @walther I installed, v11.0.0 version

Comment: @walther Thanks for comment I removed v11.0.0 and installed LTS version and it is working now thank you again.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you too. I formulated it as a proper answer, so it could help someone else in the future and we have it in a proper Q=>A format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Electron doesn't support the current release of nodejs yet (v11), so people trying to use this unfortunately need to downgrade to the LTS version and it should work. I also spent almost a whole day wondering what's wrong, but this is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: does electron support 12.13.0 yet??